# c# - Finding the full path of a file on the hard disk

Tags: c#, winforms, directory

I want to get the full path of the file named `wampmanager.conf` on disk `D`. I coded the following for this:

```
private static string Scan(string path, string file)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (var dir in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path))
        {
            foreach (var fl in Directory.EnumerateFiles(dir, file))
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fl))
                {
                    return fl;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // ignored
    }
    return null;
}

var wmc = Scan(@"D:\", "wampmanager.conf");
MessageBox.Show(wmc);
```

It always returns `null` even though the `wampmanager.conf` file exists on the disk `D`. I guess it goes to a directory like `d:\recovery\` that I don't have access to, then it crashes into a catch and returns null. But when I don't use try catch I always get access authorization error. How can I deal with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each directory you must use `SearchOption.AllDirectories` to Includes the current directory and all its subdirectories in a search operation. Try this function:

```
    private static string Scan(string path, string file)
    {
        foreach (var dir in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path))
        try
        {
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(dir, file, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
             if (files.Length > 0)
             {
                 return files[0];
             }
         }
         catch (Exception e)
         {
             string s = e.Message;
         }
        return "not found!";
    }
```